# Opening Hadoop HPROF .profile files with YourKit

Tags: java, hadoop, profiling, hprof, yourkit

[YourKit alleges to be able to open binary HPROF dumps,](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/70/help/memory_profiling/hprof_snapshots.jsp) but it insists that binary dumps made from Hadoop jobs are not valid snapshots.

The dumps are made by specifying the `mapred.task.profile.params` option with a value of `-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,heap=sites,depth=6,force=n,thread=y,verbose=n,file=%s,format=b` (as specified in the Hadoop: The Definitive Guide.

Is there any way to open this file with YourKit? Are there other graphical profiling tools that will open the files created?

Comment: You can directly hook in yourkit via its yjpagent and take snapshots. There is no need to use hprof.

Comment: @Thomsas: Thanks - do you know of any examples of using this with Hadoop? I assumed that connecting to a process somewhere on the Hadoop cluster would be more hassle than using an HPROF dump.

Comment: it is basically just deploying the yjpagent that is shipped with yourkit and instead of `-agentlib:hprof` use `-agentlib:yjpagent`.

Comment: Thanks. Such is Hadoop it's quite hard to know where and when mappers will start, so does this approach create a dump or does it require connecting to the process as it's running?

Comment: Exactly, you need to take care that the agentlib is on every node. In yourkit you can create snapshots on specific events (high CPU, OOM error) or when the application exists- you should have a look at their documentation, what to configure for the agentlib parameter. Live monitoring is a cool feature as well if you can connect to a live server.